DDR3 Address Line Length Matching Tolerance
I'm looking at a design where the maximum difference between two address signals of a DDR3 memory is 306ps. The frequency is advertised to be 800MHz, so it seems that one address signal would arrive 1/4 of the period sooner than the other, which seems way too much. Is it safe to assume that this is a bad design practice or are there scenarios where this might be okay?


Is it safe to assume that this is a bad design practice or are there
scenarios where this might be okay?

Usually the memory controller (TI example) will have specs on length matching. This also translates into timing and usually there is a conversion factor depending on the transmission line characteristics  You need to length match with respect to the command-address-control lines

Source: https://fedevel.com/forum/altium-designer/11908-ddr3-timing-budget
As far as timing this will change depending on the Er/Dk characteristics of your PCB material and transmission line characteristics (inner layer stripline or microstrip on surface) Becuase of the differences it's advisable to make the same layer changes with the same signals to keep the delays simmilar as you lenght match. If the memory timing requirements are given in ps, you can convert them with the table below or use a calculator to estimate them.


Source: https://www.protoexpress.com/blog/signal-propagation-delay-pcb/
Usually specs are given with a ±X ps or ±X mil spec attached to them, so follow that. The signal needs to get there before the clock does within a certain time frame.

Timing requirements depend on the hardware and its capabilities. The interface might support some sort of calibration mechanism that can align the timing of individual signal lines and relax the PCB layout constraints.
Without further details, it is not possible to tell whether this is what's happening in your case. But I agree that 306ps seems rather large. In my experience you'd aim for skew no larger than about 1% of the bit period. Maybe you can find layout design guidelines / application notes for the components you are working with.

In DDR3 memory design, a 306ps difference between address signals is significant, representing over 12% of the clock period at 800MHz. This level of skew can cause timing violations and unreliable operation, indicating poor design practice unless advanced compensatory mechanisms are in place. Generally, it’s crucial to minimize such skew to meet DDR3 timing requirements effectively.

Sorry, this smells like ChatGPT generated based on the format of the answer, and circling around the subject with weasel words instead of being sure if it is a problem or not. Is it an AI answer? Even one source reference that gives typical maximum skew in mils or in ps would have sufficed.

Agreed -- DDR3 is a standard, the specifications of which aren't hard to find. An experienced engineer wouldn't throw their hands up with "depends on specific implementation", no, it's standards-compliant or it ain't DDR3!
